# How to read from BigQuery as a stream

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Java + Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT

**Scenario:**

> Read Data from BigQuery(BQ) -> ETL Process in Dataflow -> Write Data in BQ tables

The problem is that the pipeline is trying to process all data before performing the insertion in BQ.

**Is there a way to execute stream inserts in this case?** I've already tried to set a *timestamp* to the elements when extracting from BQ, but it didn't work.

**Or is it possible to set the *BatchLoads* so that it inserts bulks of data time to time?**

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to do this? Is it just to make the pipeline complete somewhat faster by having some of the processing run concurrently to some of the writing, or is there another reason?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but yes @jkff I'm interested in that use-case. More for greater resiliency also. E.g. if I'm batching by 1000s of rows and something blows up in row 20,002, I'll still have 20,000 rows done.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [this link to Googles Solution](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-cloud-dataflow-for-batch-predictions-with-tensorflow). That being said, BigQuery sounds like it is being treated as a bounded source, but that shouldn't be a problem sinking data back into dataflow, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery-stream-data-python).